# Text Positioning in Safari

Tags: html, css, macos, safari, css-position

I've encountered a strange issue with text positioning in Safari for buttons on a site I've been working on.

**1. Is it possible to keep the text center aligned on the buttons while using *left: ...;* ? Would this fix the issue?**

**2. Would placing *span* in a relatively placed div *.text-pos* with a sub-class *.text-pos span* ... *position: absolute;* be bad form? Would it fix the issue?**

Code:

```css
.button a span {
 z-index: 2;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 12%;
 color: #000000;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 4vmin;

}

.button a img {
 
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="button antiques">
 <a href="/landing/gallery/antiques/antiques.html">
  <img alt="antiques" src="/assets/img_style/plank.png">
  <span>ANTIQUES</span>
 </a>
</div>
```

Did not include `left: ...;` as the text needs to be center aligned on the button.

Result(too new to post images):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFLJ9.png

My first thought was that the issue was with vmin, but:

> 1- Text scales appropriately with browser adjustments.
>
> 2- Text on the hover(upper left image frame) also uses vmin, but is
>   appropriately positioned.

In reference to point two, the text is placed in a relatively positioned div container to force aspect ratio like so:

```html
<div id="wide-container"> /* position: relative; */
    <div id="content"> /* position: absolute; */
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't have ready access to an OSX machine so any input would be appreciated!

Open minded to any other approaches you may have to offer. Thank you (:

**SOLVED**

```css
.button {
 
 height: 6vmin;
 margin-top:1.5vmin;
 margin-bottom:1.5vmin;
 position: relative;
  
  }

.button a {
 
 height: 100%;
 
}

.button:before a {
 
 content: "";
 display: block;
 
}

.button a span {
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 top: 9%;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 4vmin;

}
```

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: @Adam For the text on the left hand buttons to display in the proper location. The text is properly positioned on firefox, chrome, and IE, but not Safari.

Comment: What is the proper position?

Comment: Centered on the container... @Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by setting the button to be relatively positioned while leaving the text position as absolute. Solution outlined in more detail in the edited question.

The problem came from my misunderstanding of how browsers treat the box model differently. Safari seemed to be taking the contained elements and floating them left individually since the the image had no positioning attributes.

This solution displays more or less the same on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.